# Need to change the value of attribute to another value with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Below is my code:

```
<div class="at-custom-sidebar-count" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">10</div>
```

As you can see above, the value "10" is what I want to change but I'm not sure to go about it.

I've tried searching on here, but I did not get satisfying answers.

Say, when website loads, a listener will check for the specific attribute, and once it detects, it will change its value to 100. So from 10 to 100.

I know this can be done with PHP but I'm very new at this.

Thank you for your help :)

EDIT: Here's full code. It's AddThis widget.

```
<div class="addthis-smartlayers addthis-smartlayers-desktop" aria-labelledby="at4-share-label" role="region">
<div id="at4-share-label">AddThis Sharing Sidebar</div>
<div id="at4-share" class="at4-share addthis_32x32_style atss atss-right addthis-animated slideInRight"><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-share-btn at-svc-facebook"><span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Facebook</span><span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-facebook-1" class="at-icon at-icon-facebook" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><title id="at-svg-facebook-1">Facebook</title><g><path d="M22 5.16c-.406-.054-1.806-.16-3.43-.16-3.4 0-5.733 1.825-5.733 5.17v2.882H9v3.913h3.837V27h4.604V16.965h3.823l.587-3.913h-4.41v-2.5c0-1.123.347-1.903 2.198-1.903H22V5.16z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg></span></a><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-share-btn at-svc-twitter"><span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Twitter</span><span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(29, 161, 242);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-twitter-2" class="at-icon at-icon-twitter" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><title id="at-svg-twitter-2">Twitter</title><g><path d="M27.996 10.116c-.81.36-1.68.602-2.592.71a4.526 4.526 0 0 0 1.984-2.496 9.037 9.037 0 0 1-2.866 1.095 4.513 4.513 0 0 0-7.69 4.116 12.81 12.81 0 0 1-9.3-4.715 4.49 4.49 0 0 0-.612 2.27 4.51 4.51 0 0 0 2.008 3.755 4.495 4.495 0 0 1-2.044-.564v.057a4.515 4.515 0 0 0 3.62 4.425 4.52 4.52 0 0 1-2.04.077 4.517 4.517 0 0 0 4.217 3.134 9.055 9.055 0 0 1-5.604 1.93A9.18 9.18 0 0 1 6 23.85a12.773 12.773 0 0 0 6.918 2.027c8.3 0 12.84-6.876 12.84-12.84 0-.195-.005-.39-.014-.583a9.172 9.172 0 0 0 2.252-2.336" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg></span></a><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-share-btn at-svc-whatsapp"><span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to WhatsApp</span><span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(77, 194, 71);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-whatsapp-3" class="at-icon at-icon-whatsapp" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><title id="at-svg-whatsapp-3">WhatsApp</title><g><path d="M19.11 17.205c-.372 0-1.088 1.39-1.518 1.39a.63.63 0 0 1-.315-.1c-.802-.402-1.504-.817-2.163-1.447-.545-.516-1.146-1.29-1.46-1.963a.426.426 0 0 1-.073-.215c0-.33.99-.945.99-1.49 0-.143-.73-2.09-.832-2.335-.143-.372-.214-.487-.6-.487-.187 0-.36-.043-.53-.043-.302 0-.53.115-.746.315-.688.645-1.032 1.318-1.06 2.264v.114c-.015.99.472 1.977 1.017 2.78 1.23 1.82 2.506 3.41 4.554 4.34.616.287 2.035.888 2.722.888.817 0 2.15-.515 2.478-1.318.13-.33.244-.73.244-1.088 0-.058 0-.144-.03-.215-.1-.172-2.434-1.39-2.678-1.39zm-2.908 7.593c-1.747 0-3.48-.53-4.942-1.49L7.793 24.41l1.132-3.337a8.955 8.955 0 0 1-1.72-5.272c0-4.955 4.04-8.995 8.997-8.995S25.2 10.845 25.2 15.8c0 4.958-4.04 8.998-8.998 8.998zm0-19.798c-5.96 0-10.8 4.842-10.8 10.8 0 1.964.53 3.898 1.546 5.574L5 27.176l5.974-1.92a10.807 10.807 0 0 0 16.03-9.455c0-5.958-4.842-10.8-10.802-10.8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg></span></a><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-share-btn at-svc-messenger"><span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Messenger</span><span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(0, 132, 255);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-messenger-4" class="at-icon at-icon-messenger" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><title id="at-svg-messenger-4">Messenger</title><g><path d="M16 6C9.925 6 5 10.56 5 16.185c0 3.205 1.6 6.065 4.1 7.932V28l3.745-2.056c1 .277 2.058.426 3.155.426 6.075 0 11-4.56 11-10.185C27 10.56 22.075 6 16 6zm1.093 13.716l-2.8-2.988-5.467 2.988 6.013-6.383 2.868 2.988 5.398-2.987-6.013 6.383z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg></span></a><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-share-btn at-svc-wechat"><span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to WeChat</span><span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(45, 193, 0);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-wechat-5" class="at-icon at-icon-wechat" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><title id="at-svg-wechat-5">WeChat</title><g><path d="M20.285 12.248c-2.042.107-3.818.727-5.26 2.128-1.457 1.415-2.122 3.15-1.94 5.3-.798-.1-1.525-.208-2.256-.27-.254-.02-.554.01-.767.13-.71.4-1.39.854-2.198 1.36.148-.67.244-1.26.414-1.823.123-.416.066-.647-.316-.917-2.452-1.734-3.485-4.328-2.712-7 .716-2.47 2.473-3.97 4.86-4.75 3.26-1.066 6.92.022 8.902 2.613a6.113 6.113 0 0 1 1.27 3.228zM24.873 25c-.647-.288-1.24-.72-1.87-.787-.63-.066-1.292.298-1.95.365-2.005.205-3.8-.354-5.282-1.726-2.816-2.61-2.414-6.61.845-8.75 2.897-1.9 7.145-1.266 9.187 1.37 1.782 2.302 1.572 5.357-.603 7.29-.63.56-.857 1.02-.453 1.757.074.136.083.308.126.48zM10.886 11.416c.02-.49-.404-.93-.906-.944a.915.915 0 0 0-.952.886.904.904 0 0 0 .895.94.93.93 0 0 0 .963-.882zm4.904-.944c-.504.01-.93.44-.92.93a.92.92 0 0 0 .944.9.903.903 0 0 0 .91-.928.91.91 0 0 0-.934-.902zm1.722 7.39c.412 0 .75-.323.766-.73a.767.767 0 0 0-.76-.794.775.775 0 0 0-.77.79.768.768 0 0 0 .764.734zm4.745-1.523a.762.762 0 0 0-.755.728.75.75 0 0 0 .745.79c.413 0 .74-.313.755-.725a.757.757 0 0 0-.745-.794z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg></span></a><a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-share-btn at-svc-compact"><span class="at4-visually-hidden">More AddThis Share options</span><span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(255, 101, 80);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-addthis-6" class="at-icon at-icon-addthis" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><title id="at-svg-addthis-6">AddThis</title><g><path d="M18 14V8h-4v6H8v4h6v6h4v-6h6v-4h-6z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg></span></a>
    <div class="at-custom-sidebar-counter" style="width: 48px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">
        <div class="at-custom-sidebar-count" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">3</div>
        <div class="at-custom-sidebar-text" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">SHARES</div>
    </div>
    <div id="at4-scc" class="at-share-close-control ats-transparent at4-show at4-hide-content" title="Hide">
        <div class="at4-arrow at-right">Hide</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="at4-soc" class="at-share-open-control at-share-open-control-right ats-transparent at4-hide" title="Show" style="padding-right: 17px;">
    <div class="at4-arrow at-left">Show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between server-side and client-side coding

Comment: Confusing your question because information is missing. But maybe that will help. If you want to change that value 10 through the server in php, use the <? Php?> Tag with the variable, example: <?php echo $mystring ?>

Comment: I mean something like this. Find and replace value of attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648030/php-find-and-replace-html-attribute-in-string

Comment: When do you want to change? is it on page load or based on other event like button click, mouse over,..etc?

Comment: When page loads..

Comment: The value could be anything. It wouldn't be static. So whenever this attribute is detected, it would change its value to the specific value I set for it.

Comment: First of all, your question is a little confusing. Do you want to listen to updates to this API value? Meaning, if the API value changes even after the page has loaded then refresh the template view value? Which will be a lot more complicated than you think. OR do you want just the initial value on page load? If just the initial value, what is stopping you from echoing that in your template view?

Comment: Yeah. Even after the page has loaded, if it changes/updates, change the value to the value I have for it. 

Also please check my post, I have edited it and added full code.

Comment: If it's what I think, the appropriate way to go is with a web socket. Another way is to write a JavaScript script to hit your API endpoint at a given interval and retrieve the value and then manipulate your template with the value....

Comment: I think so.....